# How to enable CloudWatch for Elastic Beanstalk using cloudformation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I want to configure my AWS Cloud Formation template to use CloudWatch for log streaming. How one can do this in CloudFormation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `AWS::Logs::LogStream` resource in your Cloud Formation template. For e.g. in YAML format:

```
Type: AWS::Logs::LogStream
Properties: 
  LogGroupName: String
  LogStreamName: String
```

More information in the [official docs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-logstream.html).